# React.js unreachable sub-components

Tags: reactjs

I want to know how I could double map inside my structure.
Left and Right show up, what's inside Right - doesn't.
this.props only returns Left and Right also, not the Items.

Navbar in the App component:

```
    <Navbar>
        <Navbar.Left />
        <Navbar.Right>
            <Navbar.Item type={"link"} route={"/"} text={"Home"} /> 
            <Navbar.Item type={"link"} route={"/cart"} text={"Cart"} /> 
            <Navbar.Item type={"counter"} val1={this.props.total} val2={this.props.addedProducts.length} /> 
        </Navbar.Right>
    </Navbar>
```

The Navbar component:

```
export default class Navbar extends Component{
    render(){
        const { children } = this.props
        return(
            <div className="navbar">            
            {React.Children.map(children, child => {
                return child;
            })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Navbar.Left = class Left extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <p>Company name</p>
        )
    }
}


Navbar.Right = class Right extends Component{
    render(){
        const { subchildren } = this.props
        return(
            <ul>            
            {React.Children.map(subchildren, subchild => {
                return subchild;
            })}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

Navbar.Item = class Item extends Component{
    render(){
        switch(this.props.type){
            case 'link':
                return <li><Link to={this.props.route}>{this.props.text}</Link></li>
                break;
            case 'counter':
                return <li>$ {this.props.val1}/{this.props.val2} items</li> 
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

On the side note... since when StackOverflow won't let a post through if it's mostly code? Not sure what else to add here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as "subchildren". Just change it to "children"

```
-const { subchildren } = this.props
+const { children } = this.props
```

Also, you don't have to map your children:

```
export default class Navbar extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="navbar">            
              {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
     }
}


Navbar.Right = class Right extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <ul>            
              {this.props.children}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much - I guess the guides I found were a tad bit outdated. They also suggested setting a displayName for each component, so React.children.map could grab it, but it turned out to be unnecessary. Same as the map itself. Going to read up on  this topic, thank you again!